# How can I use multiple jquery selectors in addition to prev()?

Tags: jquery, performance

I am trying to consolidate jquery selectors and I'm not sure how to do that with the `:visible` selector.

For example,

```
$('.my-class:hidden').velocity('fadeIn', {
    display: 'flex',
    complete: function () {
        //
    } 
});

$('.my-class:hidden').prev().velocity('fadeIn', {});
```

I know generally you can do things like,

```
$('.my-class', '.my-other-class').hide();
```

Using `.prev()` is what is hanging me up. I'd like to try to do something like this (obviously incorrect).

```
$('.my-class:hidden', '.my-class:hidden.prev()').velocity('fadeIn', {
    display: 'flex',
    complete: function () {
        //
    } 
});
```

Thank you for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`add`](http://api.jquery.com/add/) if you like:

```
$('.my-class:hidden').add($('.my-class:hidden').prev()).velocity('fadeIn', {
    display: 'flex',
    complete: function () {
        //
    } 
});
```

If you want to avoid repeating the selector, I think you need to remember the result to a variable:

```
var myHidden = $('.my-class:hidden');
myHidden.add(myHidden.prev()).velocity('fadeIn', {
    display: 'flex',
    complete: function () {
        //
    } 
});
```

---

Side note: You said:

> I know generally you can do things like,
>
> ```
> $('.my-class', '.my-other-class').hide();
> ```

No, you wouldn't want to call [`$`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) with two separate strings like that, jQuery would expect the second one to be context or a document. You'd use a *single* string with a compound selector:

```
$('.my-class, .my-other-class').hide();
```

Comment: Yep. That's exactly what I was doing. Thank you for correcting me on that!